# Relay keypress events from Silverlight DataGrid to a TextBox

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a `DataGrid` control, and a filtering `TextBox` above it. When the `DataGrid` is focused, and the user press any key except some specific ones (eg. arrow keys), I want to relay them to the filtering TextBox like the user pressed the keys there.

I can filter the specific keys in the `DataGrid`'s `KeyUp` event, but I'm unable to relay or somehow repeat the same keypress on the filtering `TextBox`. Is there any way to do it in Silverlight 5?

Comment: I can see two solutions right now: either you convert by hand the key presses to TextBox.Text changes, or you create you own control, derived from TextBox, with methods to feed key presses.

Comment: Maybe there's a better way though.